# Effects of negative energy density on properties of black hole horizon (and nearby spacetime)

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, faster-than-light, hawking-radiation, time-travel

**Some background:** Hawking's radiation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) is counter-intuitive in at least two sense. First is that it leads to a complete evaporation of the black hole in finite time, changing a pure quantum state to a mixed quantum state (Hawking's paradox, which is the violation of unitary evolution). And second is that it leads to an 'apparent' violation of the black hole area theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics#The_laws_of_black_hole_mechanics). I had asked about the latter in this question: [Black hole area theorem and Hawking radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169886/black-hole-area-theorem-and-hawking-radiation) .
The answer that I obtained there was that the positive energy density condition is violated in the vicinity of the horizon. Black hole's area does not have to be non-decreasing in the presence of negative energy density.

**Question:** What are the other known effects of the presence of negative energy density in the vicinity of the horizon? I would like to clarify that I do appreciate the fact that there is some `quantum mechanical' nature in the energy density being negative.

**A speculative question:** Central to Hawking's paradox is the property that information cannot escape from the interior of the horizon to its exterior (which would lead to faster than light transmission of information). But has this property been proved in the presence of negative energy density in the vicinity of the horizon?

**My motivation for asking the speculative question:** Thorne (Black holes and time warps, 1994, Chapter 14), discusses that negative energy density is responsible for many phenomena such as time travel and faster than light communication. Given this discussion, above question arises immediately.

Comment: information in quantum physics can be lost irreversibly, the claim otherwise is a street alley myth among physicists that has no grounding on actual theory

Comment: @lurscher can you elaborate how information can be lost irreversibly?

Comment: any measurement will lose information for good. No way even in principle exists to retrieve amplitudes from unrealised eigenstates

Comment: @lurscher Well any measurement can be realised by adding an additional system, followed by a unitary followed by throwing away this system. So it can be made reversible, which means that existence of measurement does not imply information loss.

Comment: you can prepare special 'measurement-like' operations such that they are reversible, as the experimenter never gets in contact with the actual measured system. That does not mean 'any measurement can be realised' in this fashion

Comment: @lurscher : here is a nice reference : https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/church-larger-hilbert-space
which essentially says that any channel can be viewed as a unitary on a larger Hilbert space. Since measurement is a channel, above result applies.

Comment: yes, a 'larger Hilbert space' can always be said to exist. That does not mean you have access to information in that space. Is the same thing as saying that a measurement is actually unitary because the measurement apparatus actually entangles with the system and becomes a superposition itself. But the moment you are the person operating the apparatus all those superpositions are lost from your perspective