# Question about the blackhole event horizon

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

If the surface area of a blackholes event horizon cannot decrease, how can hawking radiation work with out making the blackhole and its subsequent event horizon smaller?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black hole area theorem and Hawking radiation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169886/)

Answer (score -1):

The surface area of a blackhole's event horizon can decrease, as a result of hawking radiation, which makes the black hole and its subsequent event horizon smaller.

The surface area of a Schwarzschild blackhole's event horizon can not decrease or increase, because Schwartzschild black holes are solutions of Einstein equations in static space-time.  Same is true for Kerr black holes, and Reisner-Nordstrom black holes.

Schwarzschild blackholes, Kerr black holes and Reisner-Nordstrom black holes are not real black holes.